# How to get result query from ajax post in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have question how to get result query in codeigniter, i need to get the value of result query for send to ajax with json_encode.

The script like this..

```
public function getPost()   
    { 
    $getCode = $_POST['part_code']; 
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT count(*) + 1 as count FROM TB_TRANSACTION WHERE PART_CODE ='%$getCode%'');
    foreach ($query->result('TB_TRANSACTION') as $row)
    {
       echo $row->count; // call attributes
    }
    $phpVar = array("STATUS"=>$row->count); 
    echo json_encode ($status) ;    
    }
```

My Ajax function like this..

```
<script> function makeAjaxCall()
{ 
$.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        url: "http://localhost/IWOS_CI/trans_invent_controller/getPost", 
        cache: false,   
        data: $('#form1').serialize(), 
        success: function(json){    
try{    
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json); 
        var r = obj['STATUS'];
}catch(e)
        {   
        alert('Exception while request..'); 
        }   
}, 
        error: function(){  
        alert('Error while request..'); 
} 
});
}
```

I create the function in controller not model.
Thanks for the help and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, you will need to modify it to suit your code though:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeAjaxCall()
{ 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        url: "http://localhost/IWOS_CI/trans_invent_controller/getPost", 
        cache: false,   
        data: $('#form1').serialize(), 
        success: function(json){    
            if(json){
                var statusR = json.STATUS;
                alert( "status : "+statusR );
            }else{
                alert( "Error In JSON" );
            } 
        }, 
        error: function(){  
            alert('Error while request..'); 
        } 
    });
}

</script>
<?php
    function getPost()   
    { 
        $getCode    = $_POST['part_code']; 
        $query      = $this->db->query( "SELECT count(*) + 1 as count FROM videos WHERE id = '%$getCode%'" );
        //echo $this->db->last_query(); die;
        $queryData  = $query->row_array();
        $phpVar     = array( "STATUS" => $queryData['count'] ); 
        echo json_encode ( $phpVar ) ;    
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Niloy Saha I try your function getPost with your ajax is not working. Can you adapt my ajax function with your getPost Function. Thanks for attention

Comment: What error are you getting please specify. Check your console for errors.

Comment: The result not show in alert,, var r = obj['STATUS']; i create alert in my function. I think error in here $query->num_rows();.

Comment: Check your `console` if you are getting the correct response from the controller.

Comment: Goto this URL : localhost/project/controller/getPost directly and see what response you are getting in the page. Let me know.

Comment: I have 3 error, 1. trans_invent_controller line 131 "$query      = $this->db->query('SELECT count(*) + 1 as count FROM TB_TRANS_INVENT WHERE KODE_BARANG ='%$getCode%'');" 2. "Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\IWOS_CI\system\core\Exceptions.php:185)" and 3. "The query you submitted is not valid.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\IWOS_CI\system\database\DB_driver.php"

Comment: i change ' to " in myquery the error show only Message: Undefined variable: status. and show null below error. and i try the function in my form error show status : undefined.

Comment: Updated above. Echo the query and check in your local phpmyadmin by inputting some static variable like `$getCode    = 2;` and commenting out `$getCode    = $_POST['part_code']; ` and see what query is generated now.

Comment: It Works i try static variable $getCode = 2; the error show .Message: Undefined variable: status

Filename: controllers/trans_invent_controller.php

Line Number: 134 "echo json_encode ($status) ;"and null below error

Comment: I change echo json_encode ($status)  into echo json_encode ($phpVar )the result "{"STATUS":"1"}" but alert show status : undefined;

Comment: <?php 
$attributes = array('name' => 'form1', 'id' =>'form1');echo form_open(site_url('/trans_invent_controller/simpan_trans_invent'),$attributes)?>
<table  width="800"><td width="100"><font >Kode Inventaris</td><td><input type="Text" name="kode_trans_invent" id="kode_trans_invent"><input type="hidden" style="height:25px;vertical-align:middle;"  name="part_code" id="part_code">
<input type="button" value="Get Code" onclick="javascript:makeAjaxCall()"></td></table>

Comment: Thanks for your help Niloy Saha, I found the answer with use try{    
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json); 
        var r = obj['STATUS'];
  alert(r);
}catch(e)
        {   
        alert('Exception while request..'); 
        }   
}, 
        error: function(){  
        alert('Error while request..'); 
} 
}); I get the result .. Thanks for your help in getPost Function..

Comment: OMG, post is not running. The query running if i give static value. if i give $getCode; the error show undefined index part_code. Filename: controllers/trans_invent_controller.php.. Can you explain me how to declare textbox form in ajax..Help Me Niloy saha.. thanks for reply..

Comment: Change this line in your `js script` : `data: {'part_code':$('#part_code').val()}, `

Comment: Question closed '". mysql_escape_string($_POST['part_code']) ."' my problem the query cannot get variable post, i pass the variable with use '". mysql_escape_string($_POST['part_code']) ."'. Thanks alot Niloy Saha..